# Копирование содержимого одного элемента в другой

Tags: javascript, html

Вот у меня есть такой код:

```
<div id="1"><b class="2">TEXT</b></div>
<div id="2"><b class="2">TEXT</b></div>
```

Как сделать, что бы при клике на кнопку копировалось содержимое **b** в **div** с *id="2"*?

Comment: При чем тут слово "адрес" в вопросе, я так и не понял, да и сам вопрос, впрочем, тоже. Содержимое какого именно елемента, вы хотите скопировать? Дочернего <b> или из соседнего элемена, или всех сразу? И копируя, заменять существующий контент или добавлять к нему?

Comment: просто копировалось содержимое одного b из div id='2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function copyData(){
        document.getElementById('2').getElementsByTagName('b')[0].innerHTML = document.getElementById('1').getElementsByTagName('b')[0].innerHTML;
}
```